# WiFi stopped working when going to Germany

Tags: wifi

So I have these prototypes to show a customer using a Pi4 with Raspbian, the WiFi worked fine in the UK.  I connected to a portable dongle with no issue, even tried a VPN to see if it was OK when I got to Germany.  Unfortunately, I was unable to go (covid), but the engineer who went could not get wifi to work at all.  Over the phone I tried 'nmtui', but there was no wifi available.
So when returning the prototypes to me in UK, they work fine...of course.
Editing the 'wpa_supplicant.conf', I took out all the wifi settings in there, then rebooted.  It still connects to my home wifi!  So there is no control using that file.  I can also change this file to use DE or even change the 'raspi-config' to use DE for Wifi location, but it still works in GB.
So I'm a little stuck as to what to try next and what exactly is fighting my wifi settings to overwrite whatever I write in wpa_supplicant or anywhere else it seems.
Having tested using a VPN, I would have thought I'd covered all bases but it appears not, something is stopping it work in Germany!
There are some discussions about this for the Pi3, but wondered if someone could spark some thought for me please.
I used an alcatel portable router both in UK and in Germany.  Tested in UK first of course, then used in germany but would not connect.

I had another road trip accross France and Belgium with no issues.  I feel my issue was having network manager alongside the raspberry's built in wifi manager.  A rebuild without adding any other network manager worked fine.

Cheers.

Comment: Which WiFi frequency (2.4GHz, or 5GHz) and which protocol (802.11a, b, g, n, ac) do you use at your home/work in the UK? Which WiFi frequency (2.4GHz, or 5GHz) and which protocol (802.11a, b, g, n, ac, **ax**) do they use where you sent your Pi 4 in Germany? Without knowing anything about the WiFi setup in the location in Germany (other than the name of the country) where you sent your Pi4, no one can troubleshoot this problem.  Next time take a travel WiFi router with you for the demonstration.

Comment: Maybe something [in this article?](https://unherd.com/2019/11/ten-reasons-why-germany-actually-sucks/) :) lol

Comment: But on a more serious note, you might check supported frequencies on your RPi: `iwlist <interface> freq`, where `wlan0` would likely be your interface.

Comment: Could be `rfkill` because of the country code or lack thereof.

Comment: Lot of good answers and things to look at here.  The wifi used is  an alcatel portable router and is set for support for 802.11b/g/n.  We tested with that router in GB before the trip

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/136939/edit) and add the information about the portable router in the question. Using the same router in both countries narrows down some of the unknowns in Germany vs UK.

Comment: I feel the country change may be a red herring here. The fact is, the Pi worked with network A and failed to work with network B. You should look closely into the parameters of these networks and check for all differences, not just the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-reading your question, I feel there is some ambiguity on two different points:

1. You said 1st sentence, *"using a Pi4 with Raspbian"*. Then you said, *"I tried `nmtui`"*.

I hope this is a red herring, but just to be sure, I've gotta' ask if you're aware that RPi OS uses `dhcpcd` by default. Unless you've disabled `dhcpcd`, and replaced it with network manager, your RPi may be in the *land of confusion*. I'll assume you know what you're doing & will move on to the second point.

2. You said later, "I can also change this file to use DE or even change the 'raspi-config' to use DE for Wifi location, but it still works in GB."

###### But here's *the thing*:

In `wpa_supplicant.conf`, changing `GB` to `DE` when you are physically located in the UK, *is not the same thing* as changing `GB` to `DE` when you are physically located in Germany. Within Germany, an AP is most likely operating under Germany's rules and regulations.

###### What does that mean?

Each country has its own regulations and restrictions on wireless usage, and on how these regulations and restrictions are enforced.

###### "Enforcement" ???

The express purpose of the `country=XX` line in `wpa_supplicant.conf` is for ["Setting the regulatory domain"](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/wpa_supplicant).

The Linux kernel development organization [supports enforcement of the various RF regulatory regimes](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory). In other words, the Linux kernel itself may be viewed as an "enforcement tool". The driver used for your `wlan0` may adjust frequency band utilisation, bandwidth and transmit power levels IAW the "regulatory domain" which is encoded by the two-character country code. And don't be upset with the kernel - there are [severe penalties](https://www.commlawblog.com/2016/08/articles/enforcement-activities-fines-forfeitures-etc/marketing-wi-fi-gear-with-changeable-country-code-draws-200000-penalty-and-more/) for aggravating the bureaucracy!

When you access a WiFi AP, there is an exchange of information between the client - your RPi, and the server - in your case, the AP located in Germany. It's clear that the AP/server may deny your RPi's service request for a variety of reasons; e.g. an incorrect password - or even an **incorrect country code**.

But of course without access to the AP/server's logs (or a wireshark surveillance) we cannot know with certainty why your RPi was blocked (BREXIT revenge? :). But assuming a modicum of hospitality, a first guess would have to be the **incorrect country code**. It's too bad you didn't have the opportunity to test it while in Germany.

###### What about `rfkill`?

@goldilocks mentioned the possibility, and it seems a reasonable possibility from what I know about it. It's certainly happened before; [this Q&A was under different circumstances](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597292/how-to-disable-rfkill-after-it-has-been-uninstalled-from-raspbian), but the answer may hold a clue. What I've not been able to *verify* is if the kernel (or `wlan0` driver) will invoke `rfkill`, and if so, under what circumstances; e.g. could the AP/server instruct the kernel to invoke `rfkill`?

`rfkill` has two parts: a *userland* utility `rfkill` and the `rfkill` kernel subsystem. You can check the status of any 'blocking' by simply entering the command from your terminal:

```
$ sudo rfkill --output-all
ID TYPE      DEVICE TYPE-DESC         SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   Wireless LAN unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   Bluetooth    unblocked unblocked
```

`man rfkill` and the [kernel documentation for `rfkill`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.14-rc5/driver-api/rfkill.html) may also be useful

###### But why does the "GB regulatory domain" allow the `DE` country code?

I suppose the only factual answer to that question will have to come from the arm of the UK bureaucracy that regulates RF spectrum usage.

We could guess at some reasons this is so: maybe Germany's restrictions are known by the UK to be more restrictive than theirs, maybe the UK is not as, uh... zealous regarding enforcement. But guessing isn't answers, so I'll stop there.

#### Summary:

I don't know that anyone can troubleshoot your experience from the information provided. If you have the opportunity to try this again, my first recommendation would be to use the `DE` country code in `wpa_supplicant.conf` when you are in Germany. Beyond that, the *userland* `rfkill` command (`sudo rfkill --output-all`) should inform you at least if it has been invoked. If so, the addition of the `rfkill.default_state=1` parameter to `/boot/cmdline.txt` may allow you to disable the *kernel* `rfkill`, but reference the [implementation details](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.8/driver-api/rfkill.html#implementation-details).

---

#### REFERENCES:

1. [cfg80211 subsystem documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/80211/cfg80211.html); includes [RFkill integration section](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/80211/cfg80211.html#rfkill-integration)
2. [RF kill switch support documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.14-rc5/driver-api/rfkill.html#rfkill-rf-kill-switch-support)
3. [wpa_supplicant Linux documentation page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/wpa_supplicant); see 'Setting the regulatory domain' section.
4. [ArchLinux docs on wpa_supplicnt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant); incl. useful tips for roaming configuration using `wpa_cli`
5. [How to manage WiFi interfaces with rfkill command on Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-wifi-interfaces-with-rfkill-command-on-linux); useful info on *userland* `rfkill`
6. [The "wireless regulation datatbases" used by Linux](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/network/wireless-regdb/)
7. [The Linux WirelessWiki article on regulatory implementation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory)

Comment: A very good lot of information here and I thank you for the time.  I in no way an expert in the field, I'm a mechanical engineer by trade but it has fallen on me to get a prototype working (to a level), so we can show customers what could be done in production.  I am in the process of starting from scratch with rasbpian and will indeed, not use the nmtui method and rather go for the 'built in' option that you mention dhcpcd.

Comment: @styleruk: Glad it was useful; [please read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have rebuilt the prototype from scratch and omited nwmanager.  Testing with just the wireless router in UK and so far so good.  Next week I'm off to Belgium (providing I don't get covid again), I have given myself and extra afternoon and night before the meetings so I at least have time to fix it if I come up against the same problem.  There is no way i can test this apart from going abroad.

Comment: @styleruk: Bonne chance.  And yes, there is no way to know where the guard rails are set unless you have access to the people who set them. And excuse me, but I have to ask this: You've expressed positive indications for this answer, but you still haven't *voted*. I can understand not *accepting* the answer until you see if it works, but a *vote* simply means you found it useful. It's completely free to vote of course, and you're free to do as you wish, but how would you take it if after spending your time on this project if your Belgian customer said, "Oh - that's nice", and then walked away?

Comment: I apologies for the vote, I did not intend to not vote. Fairly new to this, I'm a mechanical design engineer by trade and am only finding a solution for something to help out etc...Finding it quite hard to find solutions to make a system look bespoke, naturally, our production offering will be a ground up designed board, but the chip shortage has left us to try a Pi to fill a need....and we will probably be told...yeah, nice...gooodbye :-)  I'm an engineer, I'm used to it.  Upvoted done.  Thank you kind sir.

Comment: I have had to produce an 8d for the wi-fi failure and I put the cause (not root cause), to being me having conflicting network management methods being used on the same system and causing confusion, which results in wi-fi failure.  I am also going to carry on investigating this to find the root cause in case it is something to do with wi-fi in different countries with the Pi.  But to do that, I will need to go back to germany, which I will in 5 or 6 wks time.

Comment: @styleruk: Thanks for that - didn't mean to nag, but some of the "contributors" here behave as if raised in Dystopia. So - I'm a EE by training, but also a 'jack of all trades' as you seem to be now. The chip shortage is hell - Amascum is price-gouging the new $15 Pi 02W for over $100 USD. Interesting times, these. I have no idea what an `8d` is... sounds like penance? Can you ship a Pi configured as yours will be to a confederate in Belgium fpr a test run/risk mitigation?

Comment: My trip is tomorrow now, there was not enough time to send a unit over.  But i have the extra time as we are driving.  We also have an EV, so there will be time to wait for a charge as I fix things or not.  I'm finding the system more stable now I have removed NM though, so maybe that was the problem all along.  An 8d means 8 disciplines.  It means you work though identifying the problem and using various tools (like 5 whys), to methodically find the root cause of the issue, then a short term corrective action followed by a long term fix, then a few beers at the bar!

Comment: I have some odd issues poping up here and there, like 'brown screen after splash', can't run video on boot anymore...but I'll ask as seperate questions.  Find it hard to pen a question when I know so little.  Again, thank you for guidance.

Comment: @styleruk: Yes - new questions are probably best. I have zero experience with video issues as all of my Pis run headless. Sometimes the hardest thing is knowing the right question! So many times after struggling with a problem, putting the effort into asking a coherent question clears everything up.

Comment: I can confirm, wifi is working fine in France and Belgium.  So I have come to the conclusion that it was a confusion of using networkmanager that caused the issue before (although I was not there to find another reason).  Thanks to Seamus for the detailed answer.